# How to match "input" and "select" elements in jQuery with 1 query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

re,

I have a simple query that works:

```
$("#test > fieldset > input").each(function() { })
```

However, I want to select "input" and "select" elements without having to write 2 "each" queries. Is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides some nice extensibility features. Here's a generic filter to select by multiple [tag names](http://jsfiddle.net/5FY2w/):

```
/*
 * element: the current element being matched
 * index: index of the current element
 * match: parse tokens from the filter string
 *
 * match[0] -> full filter string
 * match[1] -> filter name
 * match[2] -> ""
 * match[3] -> filter parameter
 */
jQuery.expr[':'].tags = function(element, index, match) {
    var inputs = match[3].split(',');
    var nodeName = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    return $.inArray(nodeName, inputs) !== -1;
};​​​​​
```

It has a performance hit in that the callback function will be called for each element matching upto the point of the filter, so I wouldn't recommended this for very large documents.

```
$("#test > fieldset > :tags(input,select)").hide();
```

Comment: Nice one, though I suspect it will prove more useful to allow `:is(...)` as a selector, similar to `$('...').is('...')`.

Comment: @Kobi - an `:is` filter certainly looks a lot more flexible. It's amazing how much work is actually done with these simple strings :).

Comment: Very nice. Kobi's and Anurag's solutions are the ones I'd go with; very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#test > fieldset").children("input, select")
```

Here we first locate the `<fieldset>`, and then all `<input>` and `<select>` elements directly under it. `find` will work similarly, but will go through the tree, not just direct children.

Comment: Honestly, I'd like to see syntax like `#test > div > (b, input)`.

Comment: you could always use `#test > div > :not(:not(b, input))` ;P

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has some Good [documentatiion](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

```
$("input, select").each(function() { })
```

Comment: Pablo, this does not filter children input/select elements in #test>fieldset

Comment: i know, i just gave the idea of comma separated selectors. Spoon feeding spoil devs.

Answer (score 2):

The somewhat verbose solution is:

```
$("#test > fieldset > input, #test > fieldset > select").each(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

or:

```
$("#test > fieldset > input").add("#test > fieldset > select").each(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

The [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector will match more than `<input>` and `<select>` elements (eg `<textarea>`).

Answer (score 1):

Oy! There's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for that!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input, select").each(function() { 
 //do ur stuff
});
});
```